# How to draw multiple highcharts using highcharts-ng and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am using [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) and angular js in my applicaiton. For a simple case I am able call one rest service and able to plot the graph using it. But in my scenario, with the same form input I need to call two rest  services and draw two charts simultaneously based on both the responses (i.e) first graph with first response and second graph with the other response.  I tried some cases, but I am able to draw only one graph, and if I try to draw the other one, the entire page resets. Any help on how to do it.

Comment: please share you code.
are you using a factory or a service?.

Is it the same factory that supposed to return both of the result sets?.

If that the case try using a service instead since factory is a singleton

Comment: @OlegTikhonov  I solved the issue. It was just that I had to have a new config in the scope of angularjs and plot it accordingly. Sample fiddle for it.   http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/80/

Answer (score 3):

This is my way to addressed your issue. It okay with me.

First: Create drawChart at service

```
   angular.module('chartApp')
     .factory('drawChart', function () {
     return {
      lineChart: function (args) {
    // Draw charts
   var charts = [],
       chart;

    // agrs: this is variable mutable        
    var maps = args.maps,
        color = args.color,
        width = args.width,
        height = args.height,
        lablesY = args.lablesY,
        lablesX = args.lablesX,
        title = args.title;

    angular.forEach(maps, function (map) {
      chart = {            
        animation: true,
        options: {
          legend: {
            enabled: false   
          }
        },
        title: title,
        series: [{
          data: map,
          enableMouseTracking: false,
          color: color,
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }],
        loading: false,
        yAxis: {
          currentMin: 0,
          currentMax: 100,
          lineColor: '#cacaca',
          lineWidth: 1,
          gridLineWidth: null,
          labels: lablesY,
          title: null
        },   
        xAxis: {
          currentMin: 0,
          labels: lablesX,
          lineColor: '#cacaca',
          lineWidth: 1,
          tickWidth: 0
        },
        size: {
          width: width,
          height: height
        }
      };

      charts.push(chart);
    });

  return charts;
  }
  };

  });
```

Second call it at your controller

```
// Draw charts
var chartArgs = {
  maps: $scope.maps, 
  color: '#0ec679', 
  width: 245, 
  height: 125,
  lablesY: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  lablesX: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  }
};

if (Object.keys($scope.maps).length != 0) {
  $scope.chartMaps = drawChart.lineChart(chartArgs);
}
```

Third
In view

`<highchart config="chartMaps[$index]"></highchart>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

Javascript:

```
// first chart
$scope.chartConfig1 = {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
  }, ...
};

// second chart
$scope.chartConfig2 = {
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
  }, ...
};
```

HTML:

```
<!-- first chart -->
<div id="chartA">
  <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig1"></highchart>
</div>

<!-- second chart -->
<div id="chartB">
  <highchart id="chart2" config="chartConfig2"></highchart>
</div>
```

You can repeat the paradigm indefinitely